# Can I import another users calendar into Outlook 2010 and maintain his color highlights?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, colors, calendar, ics

I am importing a colleagues complete Outlook 2010 calendar (sent by mail as .ics file). However, all coloring is lost: categories, automatically formatted entries, etc. are not visualized in my colleagues colors - just in a non-distinguishable standard office style.

Is there a way that my colleague also sends me his color preferences, ie. to maintain his individual coloring in my view?

Thanks in advance!
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the chances are slim any colours would be retained, since the iCalendar format doesn't appear to store that sort of information.

Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

While a number of extensions is available, the list doesn't appear to include what you're looking for (which I would guess is "Category"):

- X-RECURRENCE-ID - vCalendar 1.0 extension which mimics the iCalendar 2.0 RECURRENCE-ID (Nokia S60 3rd Edition)
- X-EPOCAGENDAENTRYTYPE - defines the client calendar type
- X-FUNAMBOL-AALARMOPTIONS
- X-FUNAMBOL-ALLDAY - All Day event flag
- X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT - Microsoft Outlook all day event flag
- X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS - Microsoft Outlook status information
- X-WR-CALNAME - The display name of the calendar
- X-WR-CALDESC - A description of the calendar
- X-WR-RELCALID
- X-WR-TIMEZONE
- X-PUBLISHED-TTL - Recommended update interval for subscription to the calendar

Comment: Dear Randolph,thanks a lot! I am afraid you are right. I thought - no idea how - there might be a way to explicitely and separately extract a user's color/category settings and to apply them on the remote site to an external calendar. But I guess this is wishful thinking rather than based on any fact.